# How to setup a secure tcp connection between nodes - Node-red

Tags: security, node-red

I have **two devices** which have Node-red installed and they **have to communicate**. I can easly send a message from one to another **using the "tcp" nodes**, but **the connection is not secure**! I do not find an application node allows a simple and secure connection between two devices.

How setup a secure connection? (identification and encryption would be great)

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Do you have to use TCP? Could you just enable HTTPS and use the HTTP nodes for the communication?

Comment: Else look at a command called `stunnel` which can be used to do a localhost port redirection over a ssl tunnel between 2 machines